Android. Gradle. Conflict of native SO libraries names on Windows
I have a huge odl Android project and now we need to update a version of some old legacy library.
We are trying to keep 2 version of the same library. Now they are totally different inside. There are no conflicts in Java / Kotlin code. They both have some native SO library with next names:
MyLibName.so and mylibname.so
Somehow on CI/CD with LINUX release build was produced with renamed names like: libee1234.so and libaa1234.so and it works fine. I think it is done by R8 or pro-guard.
The issues is - On Windows machine we are not able to make a valid build because of only 1 library is included - MyLibName.so.  I think it is related to case sensetivity.
The questions is - Because of Security policy in company we are not able to switch machine and we are not able to use case sensetivity settings in windows machine how can I resolve this issue ?
For dev mode it will be enough to use only latest mylibname.so library without old one. Before release old library will be removed.

You didn't read my question fully about security

Assuming that the Linux system did only renamed the files you can do the same. If your are restricted to that system, build the unsinged APK, open the APK file in a ZIP tool and check which .so file had survived. Rename it inside the ZIP file and then add the second .so file. Inside the ZIP file you are not restricted by Windows's file system restrictions. Just make sure the ZIP tool you use (e.g. 7-Zip) is capable of handling entry file names case sensitive.

IMHO you should simply escalate the issue up in your company. Wasting time because of inappropriate PC equipment only wastes the company's money. Get a manager that orders and admin who can enable case sensitivity for you for a certain directory on that system.
